# How Can I Make Bash Script Using Curl Show Progress Bar

Tags: bash, curl, progress-bar

I'm using the command below in bash script. (#!/bin/bash)

```
curl -X PUT -u user_name:password "server_address/directory/file_name" --data-binary @"./file"
```

However The Command Do Not Show Any Progress Data.
I tried --progress-bar and -# options.
I tried putting the options on variety location in command.
I tried the command on the command line but it shows nothing.

What is the problem?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must make sure to redirect the output to a file instead of stdout. For example with `-o` or `-O`.

This is because if you don't, curl expects that there *might* be output sent to the terminal instead and shuts off the progress meter so that the output won't get mixed with the progress meter display on the screen and everything will be all garbled.

When you do a HTTP transfer (even upload), there's an expectation that there will or might be a response body returned as well.

Comment: Thank you, It works. By the way why the output should be redirected to a file? which file the file means?I don't understand how redirecting the output to a file made the output be displayed on command line.